# How to run php sql code if jquery is successful

Tags: php, jquery

So I have a question,

Say if I have a php file like this:

```
<?php
        print
        "<div class='col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-pull-6 col-sm-pull-6'>".
                        "<div class='form-group'>".
                            "<div class='col-md-12'><strong>Forename:</strong></div>".
                            "<div class='col-md-12'><input type='text' class='form-control' id='forename'></div>".
                        "</div>".
                        "<div class='form-group'>".
                            "<div class='col-md-12'><strong>Surname:</strong></div>".
                            "<div class='col-md-12'><input type='text' class='form-control' id='surname'></div>".
                        "</div>".
                            "<div class='form-group'>".
                                "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6'>".
                                    "<button id='button' class='btn btn-success btn_add'>Add</button>".
                                "</div>".
                            "</div>".
                        "</div>".
        "</div>";

        }

?>

<script type="text/javascript">     
    $(document).on("click", 'button.btn_add', function(){
        var forename = document.getElementById('forename').value;
        var surname = document.getElementById('surname').value;
        if((forename == null || forename == "") && (surname == null || surname == "")){
            alert("Please fill in all fields");
        }
        else{

            // DO SQL UPDATE VIA PHP

        }
    });

</script>
```

How do I do the sql update on the else case in jquery? Ideally I want to validate and then execute the sql statements

Comment: `do the sql update on the else case in jquery`-> instead of asking for a quick solution, I warmly suggest you to learn the basics of web development in a structured way. You'll learn about form validation, AJAX, mysql drivers (and prepared statements...) and so forth.

Comment: Also don't mix DOM and jQuery. If you have it use it: `var forename = $('#forename').val();` And this `<?php
        print
        "` can be written smarter like this: `?>` with all the quotes removed from around the HTML

Answer (score 1):

Look into [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

It will allow you to do what you're asking.

```
.. code
else {
    $.ajax({
        url: some_url_to_execute_query.php,
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'forename=' + forename + '&surname=' + surname
    })
     .done(function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
            // notify user query worked
        }
        else {
            // query didn't work; do something
        }
    }
}
```

PHP (some_url_to_execute_query.php)

```
<?php
$response = [];

// execute your MySQL query here
// make sure to connect to database, etc.
// access $_POST array values using $_POST['forename'] && $_POST['surname']
// then something like so (pseudo):

if ($query) // $query is pseudo variable holding (bool) response from query to determine whether is passed/failed
    $response['success'] = true;
else
    $response['success'] = false;

echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make SQL query only from server side, you need some API to make it happen from JavaScript.

You can print JavaScript with php but can't execute php from client side with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to do an ajax call using jquery in order to run the sql queries.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

So you will need a separate php script to run the sql queries which you will then POST the values to from your form using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

Note the type="button"

```html
<?PHP // whatever you need here ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title of page</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", 'button.btn_add', function() {
      var forename = $("#forename").val();
      var surname = $("#surname").val();
      if (!forename || $.trim(forename) == "" || !surname || $.trim(surname) == "") {
        alert("Please fill in all fields");
      } 
      else {
        $.post("update.php", {"forename": forename,"surname": surname}, function(res) {
          $(".btn-success").parent().append("<div>" + res + "</div>");
        }
     });
   });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class='col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-pull-6 col-sm-pull-6'>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-md-12'><strong>Forename:</strong>
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-12'>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='forename'>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-md-12'><strong>Surname:</strong>
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-12'>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='surname'>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-6'>
        <button id='button' type="button" class='btn btn-success btn_add'>Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```